# How to integrate TypeORM with schematics

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

As mentioned [in this post](https://trilon.io/blog/introducing-cli-generators-crud-api-in-1-minute). NestJS's schematics new feature able to generate CRUD easily, but the generator is generic and not related to any ORM.

How can I connect the generated CRUD by schematics with TypeORM?